# AvalonEdit How to Create indent guide lines?

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

[image]

How to Create  indent guide lines in AvalonEdit, just like in Visual Studio?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.